# How to disable side pannel of kepler.gl map?

Tags: kepler

I am working on `kepler.gl`. I want to disable the side panel of `kepler.gl` map. I don't want to show the side panel of `kepler.gl` to my customer. This is my code to display my data on `kepler.gl` map. In this code, I am reading data from API and display that data to `kepler.gl` map?

```
import React from "react";
import keplerGlReducer from "kepler.gl/reducers";
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { taskMiddleware } from "react-palm/tasks";
import { Provider, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import KeplerGl from "kepler.gl";
import { addDataToMap } from "kepler.gl/actions";
import useSwr from "swr";

const reducers = combineReducers({
  keplerGl: keplerGlReducer
});

const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(taskMiddleware));

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Map />
    </Provider>
  );
}

function Map() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { data } = useSwr("covid", async () => {
    const response = await fetch(

"https://gist.githubusercontent.com/leighhalliday/a994915d8050e90d413515e97babd3b3/raw/a3eaaadcc784168e3845a98931780bd60afb362f/covid19.json"
    
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    
    return data;
  });
  console.log(data);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      dispatch(
        addDataToMap({
          datasets: {
            info: {
              label: "COVID-19",
              id: "covid19"
            },
            data
          },
          option: {
            centerMap: true,
            readOnly: false
          },
          config: {}
        })
      );
    }
  }, [dispatch, data]);

  return (
    <KeplerGl
      id="covid"
      mapboxApiAccessToken="pk.eyJ1IjoiYWxpcmF6YTcwNSIsImEiOiJjazh5d2hjb3AwOHBqM2VsY21wOHo5eXprIn0.9G5CE4KqfbvU9HQ6WBuo3w"
      width={window.innerWidth}
      height={window.innerHeight}
    />
  );
}
```

Can anyone help me with how can I disable the side panel of `kepler.gl` map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addDataToMap method, you should use options instead of option and also you should set readOnly: true

```
options: {
   centerMap: true,
   readOnly: true
}
```